# How to add a service to the S runlevel in Debian?

Tags: debian, boot, service, runlevel

I have the following script (what it does exactly is not important):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          watchdog_early
# Required-Start:    udev
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Start watchdog early.
### END INIT INFO

# Do stuff here...
```

I insert it into the S runlevel by invoking:

```
insserv watchdog_early
```

The aproriate link is created in /etc/rcS.d:

```
S04watchdog_early -> ../init.d/watchdog_early
```

and /etc/init.d/watchdog_early is executable (has mode 755).

Despite all this, it is NOT being run at boot. Why?

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing for some reason rather than not running? Check your logs add some debug messages etc ?

Comment: No, it's not failing. I added a bunch of debug messages. In a desperate move I even put "reboot -f" there so I know it runs when the device reboots during bootup... nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Post the full script.

Your shebang line, "#!/bin/sh -e" will exit on error.  If the error condition is met before your debug output / lines run, you won't see them.

Alternately, remove the '-e' option and retry your script.